# Find patterns in numbers based on the similarity of characters?

Tags: code-golf, string

### Task

The task is to write a script that accepts a number from 1 to 20 inclusive. It will then check if the number has a character that is found in every number that was entered before it. If the number has a character in common it will ask for another number. However if the number does not have a character in common with any of the previous numbers the program will halt

You are given the following array which is named as numbers

```
{"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty"}
```

#### Example runs

Say the following number is given

```
1
```

There are no previous numbers so it shares a character will every previous number. So the program will ask for another number, let the following number be given

```
3
```

one and three both share the character "e" so this is a valid number. So we given another number, let the following number be given

```
4
```

four does not share the "e" common to both one and three so this breaks the pattern so the program now stops

Here is another run with just the output of the program shown

```
5
15
17
3
7
8
2
```

This script also had the pattern of numbers with the letter "e"  which caused "two" to break the pattern

Comment: Are you sure about requiring `the pattern is broken`? It's [generally frowned upon](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/41042) to require long inputs/outputs in something other than [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]

Comment: It can be omitted if it would cause trouble in languages it is good practice to have a message when a program halts though

Comment: I will reduce the size of the string to "stopped"

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! No offense, but in code golf we generally don't concern ourselves with good practice. It is more useful to focus on the meat of the challenge, in this case determining if the number given fits the pattern. On a similar vein, I'd recommend being able to take the file `numbers.txt` through STDIN/function argument/etc. instead of explicitly requiring file I/O as that could restrict some languages from competing. Other than that, nice first challenge!

Comment: I would also recommend posting future challenges in the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for refinement before posting.

Comment: Should the input be echoed as suggested by "Here is another run with just the output of the program shown" or is it enough to just accept input until no overlap remains?

Comment: Does "You are given the following array which is named as numbers" imply this is free (no byte cost, eg, it may be an input, in a variable, etc...)?

Comment: It may be inputted into the system before the script is run so it would have no bytes cost. You should explain how the numbers array was inputted into the program

Comment: I wouldn't recommend specifying a name for the array. There are plenty of languages where `numbers` isn't a valid variable name. (For example, in Perl, a variable holding an array would need to have a name starting in `@`.)

Comment: Can we stop the program with an error?

Comment: The program can end in a error as long as long as no output is written to the screen because of the error

Comment: Does STDERR count as screen?

Comment: STDERR counts as screen

Comment: So...no errors. Got it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](http://pypy.org/), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

Saved two bytes thanks to @ovs!

```python
s=set(''.join(l))
while s:s&=set(l[input()-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzLasMwEEX3@grVi9qCpuCUkhLIpuAu2w8IWZh0Uk1RJaEZx/HXu3pFiLlnHvf6hbWz241f/LKaw7FxFpqnhmeXqg6QuoubQhK8po7wlipcwUYF/NEc1WIxlqGpW57BZBNrDAx5ltLuiJdKMfROyVo5hxdM@RVjqOWlOa10IOCubZ9/HdrOKCVmjQYk7ekxr8wRrZ@4U5v@pFYOy17I@OowcxiRQL6PBMPtDJ7R2a79dCxHY8qhPDtL0x98P7RKQD6Sw9fHEIILJc@PROur6OPfiRexE29iK/p/)

Renamed `numbers` to `l`. If that's not okay then add 10 bytes for `l=numbers`.